# Getting error when try to run android react-native project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm

When i want to run react-native run-android command i see

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 998 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

  > Cp65001
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

  > Cp65001
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
at C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\tmpProjets\beetv-app\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! BeeTVApp@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the BeeTVApp@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Blerr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-19T10_46_33_609Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

run this command from the project path `npx jetify` and check

Comment: it's return "Jetifier found 998 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers..."

Comment: and cmd npx react-native info retunrs
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.17763
    CPU: (12) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
    Memory: 6.70 GB / 15.94 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.11.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.13.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  npmPackages:
    react: ^16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5